# How do i implement symmetric relationship with node reference module in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes

i have a content type with one node reference field to same content type and so i related that content type as like  A->B,B->C,C->D,D->E and so on.But i want to relate E to C,B and A along with D automatically and so i can list out all A,B,C & D in E node page as referenced nodes.Can you tell me how can i implement this type of references in Drupal 7?

Comment: Highly technical question, for such a low acceptance rate. Consider accepting a few answers on your previous questions?

Comment: [ask] might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to look at the relation module. It allows creations of symmetric associations which involve more than to entities. Haven't tried it myself, though.